# Redirect After Login : Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication

In my ASP.NET Web Application, the project structure is shown by the following image:

[image]

The Web.config of the Site has form authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />      
</authentication>
```

And the Web.config of the Pages folder has:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I have an User admin with role Admin. After successful Login I am trying to redirect the user in Home.aspx resides in the Pages folder as:

```
protected void EMSLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {
    TextBox UserNameTextBox = EMSLogin.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
    TextBox PasswordTextBox = EMSLogin.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text)) {
    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

But it is not working. It is again redirecting to the Login page i.e., Login.aspx with the URL: `localhost:3695/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPages%2fHome.aspx`.

How can I achieve this? Any information will be very helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Membership.ValidateUser` only validates the username and password against the membership provider. It doesn't emit the authentication cookie.

If you want to do this you need to use the [`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method before redirecting:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text)) 
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home.aspx");
}
```

or if in your web.config you set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Pages/Home.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

you could also use the [`RedirectFromLoginPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) method which will emit the authentication cookie and redirect you to the default page:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text)) 
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
}
```